# how to use redshift embeded code without login?

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to tableau and I want to integrate tableau server in our application through iframe, I am passing http URL with authentication details like username and password but whenever I am accessing tableau it is asking for username and password.So please suggest me that how can I access tableau without redirecting to login page.

Comment: merawalaid is correct: if your issue is when viewing the report once published, you should embed your redshirt credentials at the point of publishing. If you want to stop being prompted when you open the file on Tableau desktop, then unfortunately you can't, this is a security requirement - can be a little frustrating, but it keeps your data secure.

Answer (score 0):

Passing username and password in URL is very insecure. 
I could't make that work even in my 'experiment box' where security was not a concern. Tableau server kept on redirecting users to it's login page.

Instead you should try 'trusted authentication' : [read more..](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_concepts_authentication.htm)

You could also ensure that the data-sources in your workbooks are set to embed credentials mode instead of prompting for data source credentials every time.